# adding aerial photo layer

Tags: arcpy, layers

I have written a script to add a list of the aerial photo in sid format to a mxd. It works although the layers are displayed blue.

Is there a way to change the display to black and white with ArcPy?

[image: blue image i dont want]
[[image: black white image i want]]

```
import arcpy,os
    def addLayer(current_mxd, filePath):
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(current_mxd)[0]
        newlayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(filePath)
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, newlayer,"BOTTOM")
    projectlocation = ""

    projectID = ""

    prep = "x" + "\n" + "x" + "\n" + "x"

    projectClientName = "HV" + "\n" + "Environmental Site Assessment"  + "\n" + ""


    #### add edmonton imagery to app folder #####
    filePathList = [r'V:\1102\active\110220065\gis\imagery\aep\1950_0135_041-ps.sid',r'V:\1102\active\110220065\gis\imagery\aep\1962_0818_077-ep.sid']
    coe = [r'r'Q:\Images\EDMONTON_IMAGERY\2012\EDMONTON_2012_Colour.sid']
    coeLayer = [r'Q:\Images\EDMONTON_IMAGERY\2014\2014.lyr',r'Q:\Images\EDMONTON_IMAGERY\2015\2015.lyr']

    current_mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'C:\Users\vlaw\Desktop\Application\template\mxd\historical_template.mxd')
    cwd =  os.getcwd()
    for frame in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(current_mxd):
        frame.spatialReference = arcpy.SpatialReference(os.path.join(cwd, 'projection','NAD 1983 3TM 114.prj'))

        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(current_mxd,"",frame):
            if lyr.name == "Site_Boundary":
                lyr.replaceDataSource(r'V:\1102\active\110220065\gis\project_data',"SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE","study_area") 
                frame.panToExtent(lyr.getExtent())
            for a in filePathList:
                b = os.path.basename(a)
                d = b.replace(".sid","")
                year = b[0:4]
                photoID = b[5:13].replace('_',' ')
                addLayer(current_mxd,a)

                projectNumber = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(current_mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "ProjectNumber or FigureID")[0]
                projectNumber.text = projectID
                projectLocation = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(current_mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "Project Location Line")[0]
                projectLocation.text = projectlocation
                projectLocation.elementPositionY = 1.7813 
                QAQC = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(current_mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "Prepared By text block")[0]
                QAQC.text = prep
                clientProjectName = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(current_mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "Client/Project Name")[0]
                clientProjectName.text = projectClientName
                clientProjectName.elementPositionY = 1.6322
                figureNumber = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(current_mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "Figure Number1")[0]
                figureNumber.text = year
                reference = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(current_mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "reference")[0]
                reference.text =reference.text.replace("REPLACE",photoID).replace("YEAR",year)
                mxdName = "fig_"+year+"_historical.mxd"
                ws = r'V:\1102\active\110220065\gis\figures\historical'
                pdf_folder= os.path.join(ws, "pdf") 
                current_mxd.saveACopy(os.path.join(ws,mxdName))                    
                pdf_name = mxdName.replace(".mxd",".pdf")
                output = os.path.join(pdf_folder, pdf_name)
                arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(current_mxd, output, resolution =250)
                if lyr.name == d:
                    lyr.visible = False 



                c = mxdName+ "\n" + "Exported map file: " + str(pdf_folder) + "\n"
                print c
```

Comment: Where's the script? We can't guess where your code needs improvement without seeing the code snippet.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I have added the code and it works. I think I am going to use ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management to change the display to black and white. Hopefully it works.

Comment: Please provide a [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) rather than a wall of code.